# mysql query not giving correct results

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table called records which has several columns, one of which is fromphone which represents a phone number.  I can run this query to see the different phone numbers:

```
SELECT DISTINCT fromphone
FROM records
```

and it shows the different phone numbers.

However, if I run this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM records
WHERE fromphone = '123-456-7890'
```

where fromphone is a phone number in the table, no results get returned.

Comment: What is the data type of the fromphone column? Please post the schema of your table.

Comment: Perhaps its the format your phone number is stored and so an exact match is not found. Why don't you try using - SELECT * FROM records WHERE fromphone LIKE '%<Full or part of phone number>%'

Comment: For leading and trailing spaces in your data you can even try using - 
WHERE LTRIM(RTIRM(fromphone)) = '123-456-7890'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure there is a record with phone number as `123-456-7890` in the database table? There maybe some leading or trailing space in it.

Try to use `LIKE` and `%%` operator, do it like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM records
WHERE fromphone LIKE '%123-456-7890%'
```

Comment: That worked.  Not sure why/how leading or trailing spaces are in there

Answer (score 1):

The most likely scenario is that the exact string, '123-456-7890' is not in that column.  Try using `LIKE` instead of `=`, in case there's some extra spaces or something thats causing the equal not to match the phone number.

Answer (score 0):

If you have leading/trailing spaces, you can just use TRIM()

```
SELECT *
FROM records
WHERE TRIM(fromphone) = '123-456-7890'
```

Using LIKE with the leading and trailing wildcard can get very slow if you have a lot of rows in the records table because MySQL has to do a full table scan when you do that.